# Chrome v60 getting closed abruptly with selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome-driver 2.32 and chrome v60 official build(32bit). While running testsuite, for some of the TCs, chrome is opening and closing properly but, randomly, in between for some of the TCs, chrome opens and gets closed immediately, without loading URL. This stops entire execution with failure. This issue seems to have started with chrome v60. Any solution will help me.

Comment: Use chrome 59 probably?

Comment: But, I am using corporate VDI. No way and access to roll back to prev. version. Actually, it should work with latest version. Any idea why its not working?